# How can I delete my local json file? AIR & Flash Builder 4.5

Tags: json, actionscript-3, flash, air

In my first AIR application(Using flash builder 4.5), I am trying to

1. Create a JSON file using add button and save it in my documents.
2. Read my JSON file and display it in my datagrid in AIR application.
3. Update JSON file using the form.(need help here)
4. Delete JSON file and remove it from the grid using a button.(need help here)

Here is my code:

```
protected function onInit(event:FlexEvent):void {
            _documentArr = new ArrayCollection();
            var fileDir:File = File.documentsDirectory;
            fileDir = fileDir.resolvePath("data");

            var files:Array = fileDir.getDirectoryListing();

            for ( var i:int = 0; i < files.length; i++ ) {
                var file:File = File( files[i] );

                var inputStream:FileStream = new FileStream();
                inputStream.open(file, FileMode.READ);
                var dataStr:String = inputStream.readUTFBytes(inputStream.bytesAvailable);

                if ( dataStr != "" ) {
                    var data:Object = JSON.parse(dataStr);
                    _documentArr.addItem(data);
                }
            }
        }
```

Here is my grid:

```
<s:DataGrid id="grid" width="100%" height="100%" requestedRowCount="4" dataProvider="{_documentArr}"
            click="grid_clickHandler(event)">

    <s:columns>
        <s:ArrayList>
            <s:GridColumn dataField="wText" headerText="Work Order No."></s:GridColumn>
            <s:GridColumn dataField="requestDate" headerText="Date Requested" labelFunction="labelDate"></s:GridColumn>
            <s:GridColumn dataField="client" headerText="Client"></s:GridColumn>
            <s:GridColumn dataField="cPerson" headerText="Contact Person"></s:GridColumn>
            <s:GridColumn dataField="add" headerText="Address"></s:GridColumn>
            <s:GridColumn dataField="pnText" headerText="Plate #"></s:GridColumn>
            <s:GridColumn dataField="bnText" headerText="Body #"></s:GridColumn>
            <s:GridColumn dataField="atText" headerText="Assigned To"></s:GridColumn>   
        </s:ArrayList>
    </s:columns>

</s:DataGrid>
```

Here is my delete Button:

```
protected function onDelete(eventObj:CloseEvent):void {

            if( eventObj.detail == Alert.YES) {
            _documentArr.removeItemAt(grid.selectedIndex);

            }
```

What I am trying to do here, after creating a JSON file, the JSON file will be encoded in my datagrid. After that, the JSON file will be displayed in my datagrid, and whenever I click the selectedIndex in the datagrid and clicked the delete button, I want both selectedIndex and JSON file to be deleted.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting is very simple - much like the saving. I don't see where you're actually saving those file (only reading is provided), but AIR reference can help you: [http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html#deleteFile()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html#deleteFile%28%29)

It should be something similar to:

```
var targetDir:File = new File();
var targetFile:File = targetDir.resolvePath("c:/test.txt");
targetFile.deleteFile();
```

I guess you need help with updating because you haven't done the saving? Updating is pretty much overriding the old file with the one that has new data in it: [http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html#save()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html#save%28%29)

It's very close:

```
var targetFile:File = targetDir.resolvePath("c:/test.txt");
targetFile.save("some data");
```

There are different ways to do all those things - (a)synchronous, different formats, all kind of extras, but I think this is enough for your problem.

Comment: I am already done with my add file which is located in the other mxml file. what I wanted to do here is when I select from my datagrid and click the delete button. the file from the datagrid and from my documents will both be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Now, this is how my delete button works:

```
protected function onDelete(eventObj:CloseEvent):void {

            var file:File = File.documentsDirectory;
            var targetfile:File = file.resolvePath("data" + File.separator + grid.selectedItem.wText );

            if( eventObj.detail == Alert.YES) {
                _documentArr.removeItemAt(grid.selectedIndex);
                targetfile.deleteFile();
            }
        }
```

Comment: I'm not at all about points and stuff like that, but just wanted to ask - what made you 'unaccept' the answer and write your own, which is absolutely the same? :)

Comment: I'm sorry Andrey. The credit goes to you but I just want to show to other people how I write my code now.

Comment: Thanks Paul, but it's not about credit, the whole idea here is about giving correct answers.. I don't mind posting your own code, of course, but at least don't accept other answers :)